# What is the purpose of allowing you to throw Checked Exceptions in Constructors?

Tags: java

I've never understood this, but why does Java allow you to throw a checked exception from a constructor?

```
public class PerformanceLogger{

    public PerformanceLogger() throws Exception{
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

The ramifications of having code like this is that you cannot instantiate instances at the class field level.

```
class MyClass {

    PerformanceLogger p = new PerformanceLogger(); //compile error  
}
```

The only thing that works is calling the constructor from within a method. So why bother? Would it not be cleaner if Java dissallowed throwing of checked exceptions ***from constructors*** at compile time?

Comment: Same would go for any factory method; checked vs unchecked [is old](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp05254/index.html)

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect: as long as *all* constructors in `MyClass` are declared to throw the exception, you can initialize an *instance field* this way.

Comment: sorry i meant java dissalowing throwing of exceptions from constructors (rectified post)

Comment: @OliverWatkins - I think everyone knows what you meant. I was pointing out that you are making an incorrect assumption about how Java behaves. Other people pointed out reasons that constructors should be allowed to throw checked exceptions).

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the same problem as with any method returning an object, no more, no less.

There is no reason to forbid it.

And if it were forbidden, how would the constructor call other methods throwing exceptions ? By catching them all ?

Comment: sorry i meant java dissalowing throwing of exceptions only from constructors (rectified post)

Answer (score 1):

### You should not be instantiating instance variables `inline`:

you should `declare` them and then `assign` them inside the constructor.

```
class MyClass 
{
    final PerformanceLogger p;

    public MyClass()
    {
        try { p = new PerformanceLogger(); }
        catch ( final Exception e ) { /* do something with it here */ } 
    }
}
```

you would instantiate a `static` variable the same way

```
class MyClass 
{
    static final PerformanceLogger P;

    static
    {
        try { P = new PerformanceLogger(); }
        catch ( final Exception e ) { /* do something with it here */ } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless they're `String`s ... or `Integer`s or ... I think I have made my point.

Answer (score 1):

Class fields initializations are automatically moved into the constructor by the compiler, i.e.:

```
public class MyClass {
    private PerformanceLogger p = new PerformanceLogger();
}
```

is strictly identical to:

```
public class MyClass {
    private PerformanceLogger p;
    public MyClass() {
        p = new PerformanceLogger();
    }
}
```

That way, you can surround your initialization by a try-catch block.

Try to keep your fields initializations within a constructor to avoid these kinds of issues.

Comment: Actually it's not strictly identical. Initializations are performed prior to any explicit constructor code. Including any try/catch block that you put in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate them with an initialisation block:

```
class MyClass {
  PerformanceLogger p;
  {
    try {
      p = new PerformanceLogger();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // Handle the exception here (omitted for brevity).
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @parsifal - Comment added.

Answer (score 0):

We can write code in constructor there may be chance to occur exceptions. We have to throw that exceptions to the method where we call the class object.

Answer (score 0):

You never know, when would it be useful. Consider a scenario where you need to perform some IO operation when objects are created. Constructors are best place to do so. Exceptions are bound to occur when you perform  any IO operation or any operation which is not reliable. So constructor only has a single way of conveying that object creation has failed i.e by throwing an exception because they cannot return any value.

Also one more thing, you can create such objects with constructor throwing checked exception in static or init blocks as well other than methods.